# JavaScript move character. Change image on clicking right arrow

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi currently I'm making some RPG game. I want to move my character with arrows. Which is working right now. But I want to change image when I clicking let's say the right arrow. Right now when I click right arrow with this code:

```
function rightArrowPressed() {
    var element = document.getElementById("image1").src = "/img/run_1.png";
    element = document.getElementById("image1");
    element.style.left = parseInt(element.style.left) + 5 + 'px';
}
```

The image change's to `run_1.png` ant it stays like that. Than just the image slides in one pose. How to change the image again when I click right arrow  ?

`HTML`

```
<img id="image1" src="{{Auth::user()->char_image}}" style="position:absolute;left:0; top:0;height: 45px; image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast;">
```

Comment: Did you try anything? Is there any attempt you made that we can use to help you?

Comment: Yeah I made that image change on right arrow click. But it only changes once and stays like that. Let's say how to change it on another right arrow click to `run_2.png` ?

Comment: Do you can add code https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Is it supposed to switch between two images only?

Comment: @hungerstar No, its 4 images

Comment: Should it return to the first image after it has changed to the fourth? Like a loop?

Comment: @hungerstar yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a counter variable:

```
var counter = 0;
function rightArrowPressed() {
    counter = (counter === 4) ? 1 : counter+1;
    var image = "/img/run_"+counter+".png";
    var element = document.getElementById("image1");
    element.src = image;

    var left = parseInt(element.style.left)+5;
    element.style.left = left + "px";
}
```

And this would make it so that every time you right click, a different image is used.

Comment: What if I have 4 images ?

Comment: @feknaz yeah, I saw the comment. Updated answer.

Comment: Okay, now it's runing haha but the image stays in the one place not sliding

Comment: what do you mean? can you post a jsfiddle?

Comment: The image stays in one place. All four images changing in one place. The character it self not sliding to the right

Comment: @feknaz my new edit might fix it. If not, then I'll try something else.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150121/discussion-between-feknaz-and-itamarg3).

Comment: No real point in using `getElementById()` twice. Query and store for re-use.

Comment: @ItamarG3 now `element` equals the variable `image` not the image element.

Comment: @hungerstar I hate the mobile version

Comment: @ItamarG3 mobile version? Of StackOverflow?

Comment: @hungerstar no, the SE app

Answer (score 2):

You can use an arry imeges sources to make a scene

```
function rightArrowPressed() {
    var slides=['/img/run_1.png','/img/run_2.png','/img/run_1.png'];
    slides.forEach(slide => {

         setTimeout(function(){ 
             var element = document.getElementById("image1").src = slide;
             element = document.getElementById("image1");
            element.style.left = parseInt(element.style.left) + 5 + 'px';
         }, 500);//add a time in screen
    });
```

}

Comment: Array for frames - that's a good concept. However, I'm not sure if creating the array every time the function is called is a good idea performance-wise. Also, you placed the same image at the start and the end of the array, so the animation will go in 0.5s→1.0s→0.5s→1.0s→... cycle after the first frame.

Comment: @Dragomok I too would suggest an array and use modulo to loop the array. That way the JS code is not dictating what you name images. Maybe [**something like this**](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5a647f208ab6aab4e63b170a0c12c0b3).